# How To Track "Similar Product/Page" Links In Internal Site

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

So I just created a new widget that would show up in a product page in my site. This widget will show several products similar to the product that is displayed in the current page. The purpose is to help users compare similar products.

Let's say in the product page A `http://domain/products/A`

The Similar Products widget will show

- `http://domain/products/B`
- `http://domain/products/C`
- `http://domain/products/D`
- `http://domain/products/E`

My question is how to track this "**Product B page were visited X times from Product A page via Similar Product widget**"? (And there is also chance that Product B will show up in the widget on Product C page)

I have this idea using the Event feature from Google Analytics. But I'm still not sure if it is or what is the common best practice for this.

Comment: What software is your site created with? Are you using an HTML editor or some sort of CMS?

Comment: I code it myself

Comment: You can make counter using php/asp whatever scripting you use or go for google analutics if you want detail information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, events are a common practice for that.
You can also simply look at the "navigation summary" report of your products pages.